Get the first and last number occuring in a (text) string in a cell



0
A
B
C




1

first number
last number


2
Top1-5
1
5


3
Top5-10
5
10


4
Top11-15
11
15




In Column B I want to extract the first number occuring in the strings in Column A. 
In Column C I want to extract the last number occurring in the strings in Column A. 
I tried to apply solutions from this question but they did not work in my case.
Which formula do I need to get the expected results in Column B and Column C?

Use mid() with find() and go 1 place or 2 either side of the "-". Be a good exercise for you.

Is the Text in the first cell always "TopXX-YY"? With XX and YY being variable length numbers?

With a recent enough version of excel you can use regexextract

It can be that the text is longer or the numbers are more then two digits.

Off topic =LET(s,SEQUENCE(3,,,5),IF(ISODD(s),s+{0,4},s-{1,-4})) you could change 3 to any number.

This formula accepts any lengths of the numbers.
B20:  =LET(perchar,MID(TEXTBEFORE(A20,"-"),SEQUENCE(1,LEN(TEXTBEFORE(A20,"-"))),1), TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(--perchar),perchar,"")))
C20: =TEXTAFTER(A20,"-")


That will only work with the later, ie more recent, versions of Excel.

Only an alternative solution it is not shorter like the very well answered by P.b Sir


=--TEXTSPLIT(A2,TEXTSPLIT(A2,SEQUENCE(10)-1,,1),,1)


Also, I am not very learned about REGEX, but following solutions of JvdV Sir on the same topic, I think this might work, and one could use the following, if while writing the Office Insiders is enabled:
=--REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\d+",1)

Or, if you want to do this in one single go for the entire range:
=--REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A4,"\d+"&{"","$"})

This works because we force Excel to return two column due to adding an empty string to a 1st AND an end-line anchor to the 2nd column. This way we returning the first occurence of 1+ digits into the 1st column and the 1+ digits that sits at the end of a string into the 2nd column.

Feel free to make edits to my answer on REGEX if anyone finds is not correct, I have made it Community Wiki


For earlier versions of Excel:
First: =MID(A2,MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},A2&"0123456789")),FIND("-",A2)-MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},A2&"0123456789")))

Last: =MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+1,255)

The above returns the digit strings as text.
If you prefer them to be actual numbers, prefix each formula with the double unary (--) to convert.

=TEXTSPLIT(A2,VSTACK("-",CHAR(SEQUENCE(58,,65))),,1)

This splits the text on uppercase or lowercase characters and the minus sign (and some extra unused characters between upper and lowercase character sequence).
This is truly by text or minus sign:
=TEXTSPLIT(UPPER(A2),CHAR(VSTACK(45,SEQUENCE(26,,65))),,1)

For older Excel I'd recommend the use of helpers or named ranges:
Helper1 in B2: =MAX(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(ROW($65:$90)),UPPER(A2)),0))+1
Helper2 in C2:
=FIND("-",A2)
First number:
=--MID(A2,B2,C2-B2)
Second number:
=--RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-C2)

So again only works with recent versions of Excel, what happens for versions that don't have text split() ?

@SolarMike Added a way including helpers. Even though I see Michi posting questions including TAKE and SORT it may be helpful for others

Typical, couldn't resist the challenge:

LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Top",),FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Top",),1)-1)*1

SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Top",),FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Top",),1)),"-",)*1

I have not tested further than the examples you gave, but sorting for 3 digits is left to you.

Thanks for your answer. Do you also have a solution which is independent from the word "Top" so no matter whatever the first word is it will find the first and the last numeric value in the cell.

Very limited answer.

@Michal it was based on a limited example... And will work with earlier versions of Excel which both the other answers won't. You gets what you pay for...

Thanks for posting these questions to practice :)
Trying with this method (Microsoft 365): replace all non-digits with spaces (IF(ISNUMBER(0 + c_), c_, space) and split.
=LAMBDA(rows_,
    LET(
        first_and_last_numbers, LAMBDA(input,
            LET(
                space, " ",
                split, TEXTSPLIT(
                    TRIM(
                        CONCAT(
                            MAP(
                                MID(input, SEQUENCE(LEN(input)), 1),
                                LAMBDA(c_, IF(ISNUMBER(0 + c_), c_, space))
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    space
                ) + 0,
                IFERROR(
                    IF(
                        COLUMNS(split) >= 2,
                        HSTACK(TAKE(split, , 1), TAKE(split, , -1)),
                        EXPAND(split, , 2)
                    ),
                    "None"
                )
            )
        ),
        DROP(REDUCE("", rows_, LAMBDA(a, c, VSTACK(a, first_and_last_numbers(c)))), 1)
    )
)(A2:A4)


